# How we we can make element draggable and droppable if that is already exit in container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on jquery-UI and I am able to make html elements draggable and droppable but these all elements are not part of container before dropping means these are present outside from container and I drag all these inside container . After dropped these element also move inside container that is fine . but then I have a idea I copy html code of dropped element and put it in container then I reload my browser window now there have three div's:
drag me , drop me and make me draggable (copied content).My problem is that which div is inside container (make me draggable) not moving . So please any one help me following is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.drag').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "body",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $('.container').droppable({
    accept: ".drag",
    drop: function(e, u) {
      var a = u.helper.clone();
      var parent = $('.container');

      a.css("z-index", 1000);
      a.appendTo(".container");

      var leftAdjust = a.position().left - parent.offset().left;
      var topAdjust = a.position().top - parent.offset().top;

      a.css({
        left: leftAdjust,
        top: topAdjust
      });

      console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
      a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
        containment: ".container"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dropped {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="drag">Drag me</div>
<div style="position:relative" class="container">drop here !!
  <div class="dropped ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; left: 299px; top: 299px; z-index: 1000;">Make me draggable</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us a working form of the problem. Use code editor to add your full code.

Comment: @hunzaboy : ok I will add please wait for while

Comment: @hunzaboy : Sir please see this example https://jsfiddle.net/ssati/bop5sodf/

Comment: please help me anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't change too much of your code, because I don't know much about your objective, but after the drop is done, I made the `Make me draggable` div `draggable` (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mtzfp07/)).

$(document).ready(function() {
     dodragable();
     function dodragable(){
       $('.drag').draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                appendTo:"body",
                revert: "invalid" 
            });
     }

```
$('.container').droppable({
            accept: ".drag",
            drop: function(e, u) {
            var a = u.helper.clone();
            var parent = $('.container');
                 a.css("z-index", 1000);
                a.appendTo(".container");
            var leftAdjust = a.position().left - parent.offset().left;
            var topAdjust = a.position().top - parent.offset().top;
            a.css({left: leftAdjust, top: topAdjust});

                console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
                a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
                containment: ".container"
                });

                $('.make_dragable').draggable();
                dodragable()
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: thank you You did wonderful but I want not copy of  "make me draggable " I want just move It but drag me have cloning .

Comment: oh ok wait for a while

Comment: @Satinder Singh check that Singh

Comment: Thank you I want like this sorry but there is something missing . that is not moving before cloning of drag me object . Is it possible first time also .

Comment: Hi that is not moving 1st time , how I can do it please give any solution

Comment: thank you man . you saved my time . thank you :) can you send me any tutorial link for jquery-ui drang and drop . Actually My objective is that I want drag elements on canvas (container) after some change in their properties save all html in database . then suppose I want to edit saved elements then I will get all html from database then again make change in their and save all again . So according to you , am  I doing right ?

Comment: are you there ? @nisar

Comment: yes @Satinder Singh , I am angular 2,pure js developer, I dont know much about jquery, I just refereed net and gave this answer. you just try and if you dont get, post here, lots of people here to help you, go on....

Comment: Can we make double click and single click events on "make me draggable" div

Comment: @Satinder Singh check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I think you have not called `.draggable()` on the 'make me draggable' element: the `var a = u.helper.clone();` contains the dropped element, not the one you are dropping on.

If you want to make the div draggable when dropped on you should check the `event target`.

Otherwise, if you want to make it draggable anyways on drop call $('dropped').draggable({containment: ".container"});

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment "Can we make double click and single click events on "make me draggable" div –" we can do by one trick, but you ll get some seconds delay on single click check here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ambdpp9/)

```
var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;
    $(".make_dragable").on("click", function(e){

        clicks++;  //count clicks

        if(clicks === 1) {

            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                alert("Single Click");  //perform single-click action    
                clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter

            }, DELAY);

        } else {

            clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
            alert("Double Click");  //perform double-click action
            clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
        }

    })
    .on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
    });
```

Comment: Fine that is working but why we add delay ? any reason .

Comment: becoz you can't do , if you done double click, its takes two single click..if you want to reduce the delay , you can try..